# Azure Function doesn't respond if Content-Type application/json

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

## Introduction

I have running Azure Function, which is written as Expressjs application.
I have simple routes there to test

```
// Test get
router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).send({ result: req.query });
});

// Test post
router.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).send({ result: req.body });
});
```

The app configuration is the following

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
```

## Issue

I'm trying to do `POST /test` request.

With `Content-Type: application/javascript` it works well
With `Content-Type: application/json` it calls function, but nothing executes, and timeout is returned.

There is no issue with `GET /test` route.
There is no issue running locally.

Need help to understand why Azure Function call doesn't work properly for POST requests with Content-Type: application/json. Thank you

Comment: Is CORS enabled on the Azure Functions side?

Comment: @Kamo, yes. I did found the core issue, forgot to share here. I will post solution with explanation soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going deeper how Azure Function and body parser work, I figured out the root of the problem.

**Be careful with `request` object**

In regular expressjs app we have `request` object, which is actually instance of Stream object, and all incoming data goes through this streaming.

So, we have raw data, and we need to parse it right way. `bodyParser` middleware has several methods to parse this data from stream based on it's type (Content-Type).
For example `bodyParser.json()` method tries to parse data in JSON format with `application/json` content type. Once this function parses data `req.body` is fulfilled with JSON object.

**Azure Functions don't support streaming**

This is where everything breaks :) Yes, it doesn't support streaming. And since this is true data is accepted different way. So `request` object is no longer Stream object. And `req.body` is already fulfilled with incoming data. For `application/json` it contains JSON object, for other content types it contains raw data which is needed to be parsed. As example I can share my simple middleware code for parsing data with type `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
'use strict';

// https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string
const queryString = require('query-string');

/**
 * Azure body parser
 */
function azureBodyParser() {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // x-www-form-urlencoded
    if (req.headers['content-type'] === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
      req.body = queryString.parse(req.body, { arrayFormat: 'bracket' });
    }

    next();
  };
}

module.exports = azureBodyParser;
```

Then use it like this

```
const app = require('express')();
const azureBodyParser = require('./middlewares/azureBodyParser');

// ...

app.use(azureBodyParser());
```

You can change it and add more handlers for other content types.
Also we need to provide some condition whether we run our app on server or as Azure Function, it's possible using ENV variables for example. It's your home task :)

**The problem**

Since Azure Functions don't support streaming, `bodyParser.json()` tries to get data from stream, and this is a point where app stuck. As a result function execution ends up with timeout.

Hope it will be helpful for all who struggling with Azure... Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

use :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));
```

to allow custom json types

Comment: Thanks @Nurlan, this helped. But it's still unknown for me why Azure doesn't work with `app.use(bodyParser.json())`. Probably smth between express and azure function happens which overwrite content-type header.

Comment: Actually I think there is a problem with content-type, as `type: 'application/json'` doesn't work while I see `content-type: application/json` in headers

Answer (score 0):

Might be late to this thread . Had a similar issue migrating an express app to Azure Functions and had to consume x-form-urlencoded values .

Used

`const qs = require('qs');`

While evaluating the request checked if the requst has rawBody and the relevant headers

`if(req.rawBody)`

and then simply

`parsedBody = qs.parse(req.rawBody);}`

Hope this helps someone.

It is a pain to host an Express API as is due to the discontinued support in Azure Functions for express